Using SGP40 sensor on STM32H750B
I am trying to use the sensor SGP40 on the clickboard Environment 2 Click but cant seem to get it to work the SHT40 on the same clickboard works just fine. This is how I have it configured:
void getAirQ(void){

     #define SGP40_ADDRESS 0x59 << 1
 uint8_t data_rx[3];
 uint8_t test[2] = {0x28,0x0E};
 uint8_t data_tx[2] = {0x26,0x0F};

 HAL_StatusTypeDef ret = HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&hi2c4, SGP40_ADDRESS, Trials, Timeout);
      if (ret != HAL_OK)
      {
          snprintf(SendBuffer3, sizeof(SendBuffer3), "Device not ready");

      }else{
         ret = HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c4, SGP40_ADDRESS, test, 2, 1000);
         if ( ret != HAL_OK ) {
             snprintf(SendBuffer3, sizeof(SendBuffer3), "Test Not Sent");
         }else{
             HAL_Delay(300);
             ret = HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c4, SGP40_ADDRESS,(uint8_t*)&data_rx, 3, 1000);
             if (ret != HAL_OK){
                snprintf(SendBuffer3, sizeof(SendBuffer3), "Test fail");
             }else{
                    ret = HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c4, SGP40_ADDRESS, data_tx, 2, 1000);
                    if ( ret != HAL_OK ) {
                            snprintf(SendBuffer3, sizeof(SendBuffer3), "Data Not Sent");
                    }else{
                        HAL_Delay(300);
                        ret = HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c4, SGP40_ADDRESS,(uint8_t*)&data_rx, 3, 1000);
                        if (ret != HAL_OK){
                                snprintf(SendBuffer3, sizeof(SendBuffer3), "Receive L");
                             }else{
                                snprintf(SendBuffer3, sizeof(SendBuffer3), "Receive W ");
                             }

                    }
                  }
             }
      }
 }

I keep getting Receive L with the HAL_ERROR = 4
void MX_GPIO_Init(void) {
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

    // Enable clock for the GPIO ports used by I2C4
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

    // I2C4 GPIO Configuration: PB6 (I2C4_SCL) and PB7 (I2C4_SDA)
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6 | GPIO_PIN_7;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_OD;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_I2C4;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);
}

void MX_I2C4_Init(void) {
    hi2c4.Instance = I2C4;
    hi2c4.Init.Timing = 0x00707CBB; // Ensure this timing is correct for your application and I2C speed
    hi2c4.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
    hi2c4.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
    hi2c4.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
    hi2c4.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
    hi2c4.Init.OwnAddress2Masks = I2C_OA2_NOMASK;
    hi2c4.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
    hi2c4.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;

    if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c4) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    /** Configure Analog filter */
    if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigAnalogFilter(&hi2c4, I2C_ANALOGFILTER_ENABLE) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    /** Configure Digital filter */
    if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigDigitalFilter(&hi2c4, 0) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
}

These are my I2C and GPIO configs
I tried everything from different addresses to different commands but nothing seems to work

According to SPG40 datasheet table 9, command 0x26 0x0F requires 6-byte parameters including CRC like this 0x26 0x0F 0x80 0x00 0xA2 0x66 0x66 0x93, you only send two bytes command header without any parameters.
